# Might as well vs might want to

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I live in Japan, and we translate these two into much the same, a sentence with which you recommend something:

> Might as well ...
>
> Might want to ...

Can they be replaced each other? Or could you tell me how you distinguish them?  For example:

1. I (might as well/might want to) have coffee if I want to stay awake, since I will be studying late tonight.
2. I (might as well/might want to) have coffee, since you just brewed a fresh pot.
3. I (might as well/might want to) have coffee to stay awake because if I don't have it, I will definitely fall asleep.
4. I (might as well/might want to) have coffee because it helps me stay awake.
5. I (might as well/might want to) have coffee because I'm tired and need to stay awake.

Comment: I think you should provide examples.

Comment: Consider the following examples: **1.** "You don't even like meat. you might as well go vegan!" **2.** "Do you think killing animals for food is bad? You might want to go vegan!"

Comment: I'm puzzled - how will putting *should*, *must* or *had better* in the examples help you learn about the difference between *might as well* and *might want to*?

Comment: I'm sorry. I should mention it. We translate them all pretty the same, so I'd like to know the difference.

Comment: There are simply too many different usages being asked about here. What do you currently know about the difference between *You might as well kill me* and *You might want to kill me*, for example? Or the difference between *You must do it* and *You should do it*?

Comment: I don't know any difference, so I asked here. I would really use them interchangeably.

Comment: Hi everyone, I extensively edited the question to make it more clear and answerable.  OP is saying these have the *same translation* in Japanese, so he's confused how we distinguish them in English.  Please reconsider a vote to close since, hopefully, it's now focused and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is an English site I'll avoid using any Japanese, but I don't think these are really the same when translated.

"I might as well" suggests that you don't really *need* something (or need to do something), but it might be a good idea anyway. For example:

> I have a couple of hours before I have to drive home, so I might as well take a nap.

"I might want to have" suggests that you don't know if you want it yet, but in the future you might make a decision.

> I'm not sleepy now, but I might want to have coffee later to keep me awake while I drive.

Hopefully this clears up the confusion.